# Evolutionary Leap Stack Ordering

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Using [Evolutionary Leap](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEvolutionary%20Leap%5d) to sacrifice a creature such as [Pulmonic Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPulmonic%20Sliver%5d) (or another sliver w/ Pulmonic on board), in which order does the stack happen?
You would place the sacrificed sliver on top, or do the triggers miss the sliver in question sending it to the graveyard?

**Evolutionary Leap**

> G, Sac a creature: Reveal cards from the top of your library until you reveal a creature, put that in your hand.

**Pulmonic Sliver**

> If this permanent would be put into the graveyard you may place it on top of your library instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulmonic Sliver's ability is a replacement effect and **doesn't use the stack**. That means that when you pay the activation cost for Evolutionary Leap, you **may** choose to put Pulmonic Sliver on top of your library, and as soon as Evolutionary Leap's ability resolves, it will find that Sliver. Most of the times, that is not what you want, but fortunately Pulmonic Sliver's ability is optional.

Comment: Note that if the Pulmonic ability _were_ a triggered ability, the result would be essentially the same.

Comment: Do you have a quote or link, at least to what replacement effect is?  I think this is the first time I've read that term (I'm admittedly casual, tho I do lightly skim posts here regularly).

Comment: @joedragons The official mtg comprehensive rulebook may be found [here](https://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/rules). It is not meant to be read from start to finish, but rather as a reference work to answer specific questions when they arise. In your case, replacement effects are explained in section 614 (at least that's the section number in my version of the rules, which admittedly is a few months old now). Many answers given in this site (regarding the game mtg, at least) reference this document.

Comment: (cont.) Together with Gatherer, it makes up the lion's share of what official rules and rulings are at all available for the game.